# Factory pattern and polymorphism usage

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I am using a factory (`BillFactory`) to determine which `Bill` to instantiate. Each of the `Bill`s (`AClassBill`, `BClassBill` etc) can tell whether provided data is range. In the factor I iterate over each of the Bills and check whether current data is in the current Bills range. If its in the range I instantiate an object of that class and return it.

Here is the code.

```
interface IBillable {
    function calculate_bill();
}

class Bill implements IBillable {

    protected $from;
    protected $to;
    protected $rate;
    protected $unit_amount;

    public function get_from() {
        return $this->from;
    }

    public function get_to() {
        return $this->to;
    }

    public function get_rate() {
        return $this->rate;
    }

    public function in_range($unit_amount) {
        $_from = $this->get_from();
        $_to = $this->get_to();
        return ($_from <= $unit_amount && $_to >= $unit_amount);
    }

    public function calculate_bill() {
        return ($this->get_rate() * $this->unit_amount);
    }

}

class AClassBill extends Bill {

    protected $from = 0;
    protected $to = 100;
    protected $rate = 3.05;

    public function __construct($amount) {
        $this->unit_amount = $amount;
    }

}

class BClassBill extends Bill {

    protected $from = 101;
    protected $to = 400;
    protected $rate = 4.29;

    public function __construct($amount) {
        $this->unit_amount = $amount;
    }

    public function calculate_bill() {
        if ($this->unit_amount >= 301) {
            return $this->get_rate() * $this->unit_amount;
        } else {
            $bill1 = $this->get_rate() * ($this->unit_amount - $this->get_from() + 1);
            $bill2 = new AClassBill($this->get_from() - 1);
            return $bill1 + $bill2->calculate_bill();
        }
    }

}

class CClassBill extends Bill {

    protected $from = 401;
    protected $to = -1; // not used
    protected $rate = 7.89;

    public function __construct($amount) {
        $this->unit_amount = $amount;
    }

    public function in_range($unit_amount) {
        $_from = $this->get_from();
        return ($_from <= $unit_amount);
    }

}

class BillFactory {

    private static $s1 = null;
    private static $s2 = null;
    private static $s3 = null;

    public static function instance($units) {
        if (is_null(self::$s1))
            self::$s1 = new AClassBill(0);
        if (is_null(self::$s2))
            self::$s2 = new BClassBill(0);
        if (is_null(self::$s3))
            self::$s3 = new CClassBill(0);

        if (self::$s1->in_range($units)) {
            $b = new AClassBill($units);
        } else if (self::$s2->in_range($units)) {
            $b = new BClassBill($units);
        } else if (self::$s3->in_range($units)) {
            $b = new CClassBill($units);
        } else {
            $b = false;
        }
        return $b;
    }

}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 500; $i++) {
    $b = BillFactory::instance($i);
    if ($b !== false) {
        printf("%10s\t%04d\t%04.2f\t%04d\t%06.2f\n", get_class($b), $i, $b->get_rate(), $i, $b->calculate_bill());
    }
}
```

The problem is in the factory class (`BillFactory`). You'll notice I have created 3 dummy instances of 3 types of `Bill`s (singleton pattern).  This is how I solved my problem. My question is should I use this dummy instances? Are they violating any [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) principle?

Another way is to do this by converting `in_range` method to a static one. Then I dont have to create instance. Also as this `in_range` method is a class specific property(means it wont change on different instances), it should make sense. In that case I have to either hard code those values in `in_range` method or make all the `from`, `to` and `range` property to be static.

What approach should I use? Do you know any better one?

Comment: Please review your code. It is different to what you speak about. Also it looks broken.

Comment: Also I'd say you can put the `Range` into an object of it's own - which probably already solves your "Issue".

Comment: with all the static calls in there, I'd say it's more class based programming than oop.

Comment: @hakre I have updated the code. I think its okay now. I can add `Range` class. But how it solves the problem?

Comment: @Gordon how about DP point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try revisiting the design. It looks like there should be only 1 Bill class (and creating 3 different instances not 3 different classes) and maybe delegating calculate_bill to a Strategy (Strategy Pattern).